# Another package being selected instead of what I am trying

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install dhcp3-server,but it is instead selecting isc-dhcp-server and its not working as per my expectations. Please help.

```
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  Note, selecting 'isc-dhcp-server' instead of 'dhcp3-server'
```

I am following this site: http://www.howtoforge.com/dhcp_server_linux_debian_sarge
There is nothing like dhcp3 in /etc/init.d

Comment: Hos is it different than your expectations? It seems like they have simply renamed the package or switched to another dhcp server in the repos. You should be fine with the one you install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article is from 2006, and Debian went through *three* new releases since then – 4.0 (etch), 5.0 (lenny), and 6.0 (squeeze).

In Debian 5.0, the `dhcp3-server` package has been **renamed** to `isc-dhcp-server` (partially because it was already at version 4). The old name is now acting as a sort of "redirect" to the new package.